# Move OpenLayers.Popup up to 10 pixel and left 15 pixel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, openlayers, openstreetmap

Good afternoon, I have a popup that is in the map and I want only move 10 pixels high and 15 pixels to the left, the problem is that when you change its position in latitude and longitude, is in another position completely and when I zoom away from the marker, what I want is just to move to the new position regardless of the zoom, always remains above the marker.

```
var size   = new OpenLayers.Size(21,25);
var offset = new OpenLayers.Pixel(-(size.w/2), -size.h);
var icon   = new OpenLayers.Icon('/openlayers/img/marker.png',size,offset);
var lonlat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(long,lat);
var proj_1 = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
var proj_2 = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913");
var EPSG   = lonlat.transform(proj_1,proj_2);
var marker = new OpenLayers.Marker(EPSG, icon);
markers.addMarker(marker);
marker.events.register("click", marker, function(e){ // on click popup
    var popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud(id,
                marker.lonlat,
                new OpenLayers.Size(200,200),
                '<div class="popup">info example</div>',
                null,true);
    map.addPopup(popup);
});
var labelepopup = new OpenLayers.Popup(null,
    EPSG,
    new OpenLayers.Size(37,13),
    '<p style="font-size: 8.5px;">always info</p>'
);
map.addPopup(labelepopup);
```

The popup on the marker as labelepopup appear, all I want is to accommodate the labelepopup above the marker.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getPixelFromLonLat` map function to get the exact pixel from a latitude and a longitude and then use the `Pixel` object returned to add or remove the desired pixels. Then you can change popup position using `moveTo` popup function that requires a `Pixel` object.

Something like this:

```
var pixel = map.getPixelFromLonLat(popup.lonlat); //or use another OpenLayers.LonLat object
pixel.x += DESIRED_X_AMOUNT;
pixel.y += DESIRED_Y_AMOUNT;
popup.moveTo(pixel);
```